# JSON path graphical builder

Tags: open-source, json, eclipse

I am trying to find an eclipse based plugin for a jsonpath graphical builder. There are hundred different tools for XPath but I can't find a single one for jsonpath.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a graphical tool, and it's not jsonpath, and it's not for Eclipse, but do you know [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)?

You can do amazing things with this command line tool! And over on stackoverflow.com there are true wizards answering tricky questions about **jq**.

Also try [gron](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron/), another command line tool more suitable for "exploratory" JSON filtering.

Comment: While it looks like `jq` is 404, `gron` is extremely useful